# How to make Scrabble game

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make a Scrabble game with html css and javascript.
I tried a lot but failed.

I tried to make that mesh with css Grid but it doesn't have borders property. And doing that with tables wouldn't not be a optimised way.

Comment: you can make it with grid easily, just keep the trial and error on, or come here to ask with the code when you have something wrong

Comment: Nobody has said that you cannot use a table to create a Scrabble board. There's nothing sub optimal about that.

Comment: Tables are actually valid here, since the rows and columns are rigid. If you use CSS Grid you have to make sure the rows and columns don't shift on smaller screens. Regardless, if you don't post any code, we can't see where your problem is :)

Comment: A table really should be used for tabular data, which a Scrabble board is not. A grid does seem the right way to go. You will need an element (e.g. a div) representing each square, and its those that you give a border to, not the parent element which has display: grid. Try it and if still stuck put the code in the question with a description of the problem you are facing.